# gutting out configs from ios apps,

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on an app that will require the user to authenticate against yelp and foursquare, and potentially facebook and pinterest( a lot of things ).
I started by persisting all this info locally on disk, but then thought this might be insecure, then I went to the next scenario which is to have a collection on the backend that has all configs needed that every time on load I go and get it.
Anyhow, I was wondering whether people have a way to gut out all the configs related to this kind of info from the app, and maybe put it somewhere or whats considered best practices for this scenario?

An example of these configs would be Oauth Token from Foursqaure, yelp, facebook, and whatever other api I need to connect to.

Comment: Hi Eddie, what info were you persisting to disk? And what do you mean by configs?

Comment: Hi Rob, I updated the question, basically outh tokens and other static URL's poionting to api endpoints.